# Wait until any condition is True

Tags: python

I'm making a program in which I want it to stop and wait until any one of my condition is met. If one condition becomes `True` while the other condition is still waiting, then the code will continue on with the `True` condition. Sort of a mixture of `if`, `elif`, and `while` statements.

Something like this:

```
until first_condition is False:
    # wait
or until second_condition is False:
    # wait

# continue the code
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want `while not first_condition and not second_condition:  # wait`?

Comment: No, I want them to work independently. If one condition becomes true while the other is still false and waiting, continue the code. Not both at once.

Comment: That's what it does.

Comment: sounds like a job for the `any` function `any(iterable)
Return True if any element of the iterable is true. If the iterable is empty, return False. ` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Comment: You probably are looking for [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and/or [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) combined with a `while`.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "wait". You mention a similarity with `while`. But I suppose you are not just thinking of something like `while not i>0 or not j>0: doSomething`, that does something iteratively until both `i>0` and `j>0`. Do you mean that program should stay blocked on that `wait` command until it is fullfilled? And if so, how do you expect that condition to become true, if your program does nothing in the meantime? Do you mean that there are some other threads?

Comment: In other words, your description (analogy with `while`, answer to comments, etc.) makes it sound like an active loop, that runs util some combination of conditions are met. While your vocabulary ("wait") makes it sound like a blocking instruction that unblock only when that combination of conditions are met. Which one is it?

Comment: @chrslg By "wait" I mean that the program should stop executing and wait until any condition is met, just like `while not condition: time.sleep(1)`. The while loop checks every second whether the condition is true or not. What I want is just like the while loop, but to check for 2 conditions.

Comment: So what was wrong with `while not first_condition and not second_condition: time.sleep(1)`?

Comment: But you seem to have already rejected `while not condition1 or not condition2: time.sleep(1)`. So there must be some difference that we fail to understand.

Comment: @mkrieger1 `and` check for both conditions to be true, if the loop is waiting and the `first_condition` becomes true, it will keep waiting until `second_condition` is also true, and then it will continue the code.

Comment: There are also two `not`s in there. Did you even try it?

Comment: Is that not exactly what you want? `while not condition1 or not condition2: time.sleep(1)` continues while either one of condition1 or condition2 is false. So ends (and execute rest of code) only when both condition1 and condition2 are true. Regardless of when they became true (in the same iteration, or one after the other).

Comment: ok, you seem to have accepted an answer.. which does exactly what both mkrieger1 and I were saying (`any` is a kind of `or`, that works for a while iterable of conditions)... so all good I'd say. Even if I am under the impression that I still haven't understood your question, as long as it is solved...

Comment: Yes I agree, `while not condition1 or not condition2: time.sleep(1)` also works, thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this:

```py
while not(any([cond1, cond2])):
    # Do something
```

Where the while loop will run until any conditions in the list are True.

---

For a simpler alternative (@[ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger)) when you have a smaller amount of conditions, you can use:

```
while not (cond1 or cond2 or cond3 or ...):
    # Do something
```

Comment: This is much more clearly written as `while not cond1 and not cond2:` or `while not (cond1 or cond2):`; wrapping the conditions up in a `list` just to call `any` on them is over-complicating matters unless you need to test *many* conditions (and even then, `not (cond1 or cond2 or cond3)` is probably better).

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes you're right. I was making a scalable option (i just assumed OP had many conditions). I Will append your alternative now